# how to do this using sql

Tags: mysql

I have been trying for an hour now but finding very difficult time achieving this.

| id | product | category | price | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | category1 | 5.00 | 1 |
| 2 | product2 | category1 | 3.00 | 5 |
| 3 | product3 | category2 | 10.00 | 8 |
| 4 | product4 | category2 | 5.00 | 3 |

What I want is, calculate `price x stock` and group them by `category` so result will be like this:

**STEP 1 (to make my question little more understandable)**

| category | total price | total stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| category1 | 8.00 | 6 |
| category2 | 15.00 | 11 |

**and this is what I am looking for**

| category | price*stock |
| --- | --- |
| category1 | 48.00 |
| category2 | 165.00 |

I tried `SELECT category SUM(price) AS price FROM product GROUP BY category`
and I don't know what's the next step, is it possible to achieve this using SQL only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in MySQL to sum the product of the price and stock:

```
SELECT category, SUM(price) AS total_price, SUM(price*stock) AS total_stock
FROM product
GROUP BY category
```

Comment: What do I do when ```stock``` is from a separate table? How can do both join and sum?

Comment: That's not the question you asked.  What you did ask has been answered.  Maybe you should open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select category, sum(price) total_price, sum(stock) total_stock, sum(price)*sum(stock)price_stock 
from product 
group by category;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the final table, is just add the stock values at the sum of the price i.e.
`SELECT category, SUM(price)*sum(stock) AS priceXstock FROM Persons GROUP BY category;`

Which in this case will give you back the last table.